# Ubuntu 12.04 x86 64bit

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, xrandr

Can anyone help me with my resolution settings? I can't figure out why the last command fails.

```
andrew@Ubuntu-TV:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.00" 85.5 1360
1424 1536 1792 768 771 777 795 +HSync +VSync 

andrew@Ubuntu-TV:~$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm 
1920x1080 60.0*+ 24.0 30.0  
1280x1024 60.0 
1280x720 60.0  
1024x768 60.0  
1440x480 30.0  
1440x480i 30.0  
800x600 60.3   
720x480 59.9   
640x480 60.0 59.9   
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)  HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
1360x768_60.00 (0xff) 85.5MHz 
h: width 1360 start 1424 end 1536 total 1792 skew 0 clock 47.7KHz 
v: height 768 start 771 end 777 total 795 clock 60.0Hz 

andrew@Ubuntu-TV:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode
HDMI1 1370x768_60.00 xrandr: cannot find mode "1370x768_60.00"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your hardware? Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: 1. I am trying to use the 1360x768 res setting for my box connected to my TV so I can read the screen from the couch. Need mode added to HDMI1 (last command that fails). 2. Hardware is an Intel NUC with the 4000 GPU, I believe. 64-bit. Connected to my Sony LCD TV. 3. Why not? I get the same result either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the update that is breaking my Display resolution options

```
Start-Date: 2013-07-04 09:10:11
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.48'
Install: linux-image-3.5.0-34-generic:amd64 (3.5.0-34.55~precise1)
End-Date: 2013-07-04 09:10:43
```

I get the following error after reboot and my preferred resolution option (and a bunch of others) in Display are gone. I rolled back the update.

```
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors

none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 63
CRTC 63: trying mode 1920x1080@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1920x1080@24Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1920x1080@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1280x1024@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1280x720@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 720x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1920x1080@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1920x1080@24Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1920x1080@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1280x1024@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1280x720@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 720x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 64
CRTC 64: trying mode 1920x1080@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1920x1080@24Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1920x1080@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1280x1024@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1280x720@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 720x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1920x1080@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1920x1080@24Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1920x1080@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1280x1024@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1280x720@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 720x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 65
CRTC 65: trying mode 1920x1080@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1920x1080@24Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1920x1080@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1280x1024@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1280x720@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 720x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1920x1080@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1920x1080@24Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1920x1080@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1280x1024@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1280x720@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1440x480@30Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 720x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1360x768@60Hz (pass 1)
```